# How to remap CapsLock fot Ctrl and Shift CapsLock to normal CapsLock

Tags: gnome-tweaks

I am on 22.04 and seen in `gnome-tweeks` that there is an option to use the `Caps Lock` as `Esc` but `Shift Caps Lock` as normal `Caps Lock`.

How could I achieve the same but instead of `Esc` I want to have `Ctrl` per default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that I found is modifying the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file directly for my used layout (variant "altgr-intl" in my case).

Then I can remap the four levels of `Caps Lock` as

- Left Control
- Escape
- Traditional Caps Lock
- Backspace

```
   key <CAPS> { [Control_L, Escape,      Caps_Lock,       BackSpace ] };
   modifier_map Control { <CAPS> };
```

It can be (re-)loaded with `setxkbmap -layout us -variant 'altgr-intl'`. I didn't have any precompiled symbols files.

Still, a rule like `escape_shifted_capslock` just `control_shifted_capsloc` would be the real solution which isn't bound to a single layout.